# How to make algorithm centred in text and take less space (smaller width)

Tags: floats, algorithms, algorithmic

How to make algorithm bar shorter?

```
    \begin{algorithm}[H]        
    \caption{Exact Invariant Simulator} 
    \begin{algorithmic}[H] \label{alg:eisim}
        \FOR{$r \in \{1,2,...,R\}$}
        \STATE Sample $\theta_i^{(1,r)}$ from $\theta_i\sim p(\theta_i)$
        \STATE Sample $Y^{(1,r)}\sim p(\cdot|\theta_i^{(1,r)})$
        \FOR{$s \in \{2,3,..,S\}$}
        \STATE Sample $\theta_i^{(s,r)}$ from $\theta_i\sim K_i(\cdot|\theta_{-i}^{(s-1,r)})$
        \ENDFOR
        \STATE Calculate test statistic $T(\theta^{(S,r)}, Y^{(S,r)})$ \footnotemark
        \ENDFOR 
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

This gives

[image]

But the black lines are too long. How to make it shorter?

Comment: How can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

I stand corrected.  You CAN put an [H] float inside a minipage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\noindent\hfil\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Exact Invariant Simulator} \label{alg:eisim}
    \begin{algorithmic} 
        \FOR{$r \in \{1,2,...,R\}$}
        \STATE Sample $\theta_i^{(1,r)}$ from $\theta_i\sim p(\theta_i)$
        \STATE Sample $Y^{(1,r)}\sim p(\cdot|\theta_i^{(1,r)})$
        \FOR{$s \in \{2,3,..,S\}$}
        \STATE Sample $\theta_i^{(s,r)}$ from $\theta_i\sim K_i(\cdot|\theta_{-i}^{(s-1,r)})$
        \ENDFOR
        \STATE Calculate test statistic $T(\theta^{(S,r)}, Y^{(S,r)})$ \footnotemark
        \ENDFOR 
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```